# Can't save location when posting node through services module

Tags: services, location, google-maps, 8

I am using services module to post nodes using rest/json. The nodes also contain images and location. So far I can upload the image and save the node, but the location is not saved. I receive no errors in logs.

Any ideas? Is there something I have to add,maybe permissions, in order to be saved?

This is the json that creates the article but doens not save the location.

```
{
    "title": "some title",
    "type": "article",
    "language": "el",
    "body" : {
          "und": [
              {
                  "value": "some text"
              } ]
    },
    "field_tags": { "und": "9" },
    "field_image": {
        "und": 
          [{
            "fid": "1364"
          }]

    },
    "locations":{
        "und":[
                {
                  "country":"gr",
                  "latitude":"55.7046601",
                  "longitude":"13.191007300000024",
                  "name":"TEST LOCATION",
                }
            ]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing the location? Node location? Location CCK field?
take a look at:

https://www.drupal.org/node/906968

If you are using a CCK location field you should disable node location module.

- Or if you aren't you could switch to a location field.

As a last option you could put latitude and longitude in their own text fields (like field_latitude and field_longitude) since gmaps module can take lat and lng from text fields.

> you can use CCK location which allows you a geolocation field, it
>   comes with location module:
>
> https://www.drupal.org/project/location

Comment: I use drupal 7 and when I enabled the location/gmap module I see a default 'locations' field in the node. I also tried to create a new 'field_location' but no luck so far.
The links that you sent is about drupal 6.

Comment: Yep, but I found myself with the same problem in D7.  If you want so use gmap and need a location field you can try: Location CCK which allows you to use a geolocation field and select this field as a coordinates source when you create a gmap view.

Comment: There was some progress. I disabled 'node locations' and I posted to the new field_location the longtitude and latitude. But in table 'location' i see that source is 0 and the longtitude and latitude are both 0.000000.

Comment: Make sure you pass the values in the right format  with decimals after a dot

Comment: I sent the following but still i get 0.00000...
"field_location":{
       "und":[
            {
                  "country":"gr",
                  "latitude":"55.7046601",
                  "longitude":"13.7046601",
                  "name":"TEST LOCATION",
                  "city":"Tripoli"
                }
         ]
    }

Comment: Also, locations may be trying to geocode the coordinates using the address so you may try to pass only the coordinates

Comment: If I only pass coordinates then nothing is saved. I just sent "field_location":{
       "und":[
            {
                  "latitude":"55.7046601",
                  "longitude":"13.7046601"
                }
         ]
    }, with no luck.

Comment: did you configure the cck location field properly? You can configure it to accept just the coordinates and make all other 'subfields' optionals.

Comment: The cck location field is set to allow only location name, country and coordinate chooser. Same in display settings. Is there a problem with coordinate chooser?

Comment: I just uploaded 2 screenshots in case you see something wrong. Thank you for you time.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2534039/Screenshot_2.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2534039/Screenshot_3.png

Comment: It's more or less how I have It. If you put the latitude and longitude from the node itself (not programmatically) ¿do you get the same error? I had a lot of trouble with coordinates too.

Comment: If I put long/lat from the broswer, either by coordinate chooser, either by by setting them into the form, they are saved without any errors. When posting from rest/json and they are not saved, there are no errors in logs.

Comment: In content type settings there is on default locations field and one field_location that i created. Is there a chance for a conflict? How do I remove the default?
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2534039/Screenshot_1.png

Comment: the default should not affect the field. I you can't save the values via json may be there's a problem on how ypou're passing the values. I use the same field type and I only fill latitude and longitude programmatically without any problem. with entity api i pass something like '$entity->$clave->set(array(
            'latitude' => $campo['value']['latitude'],
            'longitude' => $campo['value']['longitude'],
            //other elements added here (province, postal_code, country [es, en,...],additional, ...)
          ));'

Comment: I didn't add any php code so far. I thought it would work with default services. Is there a guide, do I need a custom module to do in order to save the location?

Comment: No, It's just an example of the parameters i pass, which are only latitude and longitude. You can try to put them in separate text field as i suggested in an edit. As a last option It can save you some time.

Comment: Ι don't understant where to add the sample code. In node-article.tpl.php? Or other file?

Comment: It's a little complicated to explain in the comments, and this answer would be more related on how to programmatically create nodes rather than with your actual problem.  If you feel comfortable with php coding you could use this solution, otherwise I'd suggest you to put latitude and longitude in separate text fields until a better solution is found. If you want to know how to create nodes using php I can give you some directions.

Comment: The devel module shows the following structure:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2534039/devel.jpg

Do you think the problem is with json or I need to add php code to handle longtitude / latitude?